Can I modify a quote in this manner? If so, what is the correct way to do it?
I am writing an essay on the use of cryptology in the Second World War. I would like to use, "No single operation out of the world war was so dependent on Bletchley as the Normandy landings. Indeed without the work which was done here, there is no way the landings could have gone ahead, let alone succeeded," as a quote in this text.
However, I have not explained what "Bletchley" is, and have already exceeded the maximum word count. I am wondering if it's acceptable to modify the quote to change "Bletchley" into "British cryptographers," since Bletchley was essentially an organization of British cryptographers.
If that is an acceptable way to modify a direct quote, how would I go about integrating the context into the quote? Would something like, "No single operation out of the world war was so dependent on [British Cryptographers] as the Normandy landings. Indeed without the work which was done here, there is no way the landings could have gone ahead, let alone succeeded," work?
Thanks! :)

"Acceptable" by whose standards?

By the standards of MLA

I doubt the MLA has anything to say on this specific matter.

You exceeded the maximum word count, so you want to add words? "Dependent on [cryptograhers] as the Normandy landings."

-1. That is not a style question or a grammar question but a question of presenting information in the order in which it's needed. Find a way to introduce Bletchley.

It's generally considered acceptable to modify a quote to ensure that is is understood by readers, or explain something, as long as you make it clear what you have modified. The usual method is to put additions or substitutions in square brackets.
For example if the original says:

John went to Nepal. He climbed a mountain.

But you only want to quote the second sentence, which if done literally would leave readers wondering who "he" was. It's acceptable to write:

[John] climbed a mountain.

or

He [John] climbed a mountain.

So you could write:

No single operation out of the world war was so dependent on Bletchley [the home of the British cryptography effort] as the Normandy landings.

or

No single operation out of the world war was so dependent on [the British cryptography effort] as the Normandy landings.

You can also omit irrelevant parts of a quote by replacing them with ellipsis.
